# Get YouTube Channel's Avatar/Thumbnail from URL

Tags: php, dom, youtube, youtube-api

I've searched and tried a few things like DOM and a couple API methods. I can't find any clear documentation on the API either that relates to PHP. And I've never used DOM before till now, so I'm not experienced with it.

So basicly, I need a method to get a YouTube channel's avatar and display it using PHP from the channel's URL.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the actual code for your attempt and explain exactly what is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use cURL or an alternative to get the source of the user's YouTube page, then use this code to get their avatar.

```
echo GetBetween($YouTubePage,'<img class="appbar-nav-avatar" src="','" title="');


function GetBetween($content,$start,$end){
$r = explode($start, $content);
if (isset($r[1])){
$r = explode($end, $r[1]);
return $r[0];
}
return '';
}
```

Comment: this method don't use thé YouTube API, basically it's not à good practice to get the thumbnail like that...

Answer (score 0):

Your can use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) or cUrl.

Your url would look like http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/PUTCHANNELID?fields=yt:username,media:thumbnail,title&alt=json

Your can remove last argument  alt=json if your prefer to work with XML
Here is example of response:

```
    {
     version: "1.0",
     encoding: "UTF-8",
     entry: {
             xmlns: "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
             xmlns$media: "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/",
             xmlns$yt: "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007",
     title: {
             $t: "CSS Masters Israel",
             type: "text"
            },
     media$thumbnail: {
         url:"http://yt3.ggpht.com/qC5rLzDDlKA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ijaVa2hQjso/s88-c-k-no/photo.jpg"
     },
    yt$username: {
        $t: "TJv3MtKko-T3gDGn5XFyPA"
    }}}
```

So you just need to get `media$thumbnail[url]` and use it in

```
echo '<img src="'.media$thumbnail[url].'"/>
```

Also you should take title from response and use it as alt and title attributes for image.

Comment: Isn't all of the gdata feeds api being deprecated at the end of the month?